# Scala split string regex pattern

Tags: regex, scala

I have a String that looks like this and I want to extract the bit between the pipe and the tilde.

```
{>}D003 S/N|555555~EB
```

So the result of the parsing should give me 555555 back. Here is what I tried, but without success:

```
"""\D003 S/N|.*\~""".r.findFirstIn("{>}D003 S/N|555555~EB")
```

which gives me:

```
Some({>}D003 S/N|555555~)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a simple unanchored regex with a capturing group: [`D003 S/N\|([^~]+)~`](https://regex101.com/r/ZD3rHo/3).

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/hHMyet):

```
val rx = """D003 S/N\|([^~]+)~""".r.unanchored
val s = "{>}D003 S/N|555555~EB"
val res = s match { 
    case rx(c) => c
    case _ => ""
}
println(res)
```

**Pattern details**:

- `D003 S/N\|` - match a literal char sequence `D003 S/N|`
- `([^~]+)` - capturing group 1 matching 1 or more chars other than `~`
- `~` - a literal char `~`.

Comment: But I could also have Strings that contain "{>}D004 S/N|555555~EB" instead of "{>}D003 S/N|555555~EB". So I would only like to parse the ones with a D003 S/N on it. How could I do that?

Comment: Check if the input string contains `D003 S/N` in it and only then extract the value. If the value comes *before* the number, just add it to the regex: `"""D003 S/N.*\|([^~]+)""".r.unanchored`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/KFxNmN).

Comment: But it still matches for messages without tild,  "{>}D003 S/N|55555 EB. I want both conditions to be matched.

Comment: Nothing easier, just add it at the end of the pattern :) I will update the answer now, since you clarified the requirements. ... Done.